# Как вытащить более 1500 записей с помощью api yandex

Tags: яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api, яндекс-карта-api

results=500
skip - стоит ограничение, максимум может быть равен 1000
skip перебираем, при первом запросе 0, второй запрос 500, третий запрос 1000 и всё на выходе мы получаем 1500 записей, как быть если требуется вывести +1500 записей?

url = 'https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Аптека&results=500&skip=1000&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=xxx'

Как обходной путь можно ограничивать область поиска методом bbox или ll, spn, но это мягко говоря не очень удобно.

Comment: А на `results` тоже есть ограничение?

Comment: skip=1500 не работает?

Comment: results максимум 500;
skip=1500 не работает, ошибка 403 с инфой о том что skip более 1000 не допустимо

Comment: Ну, спрашивайте авторов `API`. Они наверное денег хотят за запросы без ограничений? )

Comment: с сайта авторов api: "Если у вас возникли вопросы по использованию API, поищите ответ в сообществе API Карт на Stack Overflow (сообщество на русском). При поиске используйте метку yandex-geocoding-api.

Если вы не нашли свой вопрос на Stack Overflow, задайте его там. "
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/feedback/troubleshooting.html

Своего вопроса не нашел, соответственно задал )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование сервиса [ППО](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosearch/) не предназначено для выгрузки каталогов. Более того сохранение получаемых от сервиса данных нарушает [условия использования сервиса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/geosearch.html#geosearch), поскольку даже платные тарифы такой опции не предоставляют.

Потому возможности выгружать многотысячные ответы от сервиса просто не существует. Сервис её не реализовывал.

API Поиска по организациям следует использовать для поиска единичных объектов - если при указании всех параметров, объектов в области больше, чем отдает сервис, следует скорректировать и уточнить запрос. Все результаты сформированы по релевантности, и общее количество объектов в выдаче это лишь маркер, по которому вы судите о точности запроса.

Нельзя считать всю поисковую выдачу нашего сервисе релевантной от первого объекта до последнего, это некорректно. Сервис не подходит для решения подобных задач.